# Regex matching on record boundries

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to write a python script which searches through large text files for Oracle Error numbers.  These files have no guaranteed record delimiters. Because of this I am performing the operation in multi-byte blocks.

Regex matching within the block appears to be a trivial task, however I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around a partial match at the beginning or end of a block.

The full regex to be matched is an oracle error number similar to the following

```
`"ORA\-[0-9]{1,5}"`
```

How would one go about writing a regex matching a subset of this? As an example; a partial match at the end of the block would be one of the following:

```
(O$, OR$, ORA$, ORA\-$, ORA\-n$, or ORA\-nn$)
```

Conversely, at the start of the block I would search for

```
(^n, ^nn, ^\-nn, ^A\-nn, or ^RA\-nn)
```

This partial match at the end of a block would be saved for possible comparison against the start of the next block.

Positive lookaround appears promising, however doesn't match the additional characters I'm requiring. Can this style of lookup be efficiently performed via regex?

Comment: How is the error code getting split across different lines in the first place?

Comment: There is no concept of a "line"  as there is no guaranteed delimiter.  That's the reason I have to read the file in a set block size.

Comment: It might be simpler to just have 8 characters overlap between each block. Consider using `myfile.seek(-8, 1)` to rewind the file by 8 bytes, if you don't have a better way to make the overlap happen.

Comment: Wouldn't that then allow for the possibility of double counting an error?

Comment: I think you will just have to check 2 blocks (read the 1st, then the 2nd), concatenate and check with your regex. Then, read the 3rd, concatenate with the 2nd, and check with regex... until EOF.

Comment: Oh, I misread the pattern. I though it was always going to have five digits (and thus the whole pattern would be 9 characters long). If it's variable length, you'd have to be more clever.

Comment: Blckknght, I still believe you may be onto something.   re.finditer will return an iterator object of regex matches.  match.span() will return the location.  By counting my processed blocks, and keeping track of match locations, I should be able to verify if I have a match collision. Once I have a working proof of concept I'll post it.

Comment: How big is "large," by the way?

Comment: The file I've been running it against as a test is 1.8gb.  That's typical of what I anticipate.

Comment: I did have a go at a method similar to what blckknght mentioned. I'm feeding in the last 8 bytes of the previous block back into my function call performing the match.  It does work to resolve some issues of a match spanning two blocks, but not all.  I haven't yet determined an efficient way of resolving a numerical span similar to [...ORA-02][501...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real answer here is that you don't want to use regular expressions in the raw. Regular expressions are a bit too high level for what you want to do. What you need is a **tokenizer**. A tokenizer is a well understood piece of technology since it's a vital part of every compiler. It's what breaks text down into *lexemes*, the individual blocks of text that mean something. The key characteristic that's important to you here is that a tokenizer looks at *one character at a time* to tokenize a source string. This characteristic will allow you to stream the file rather than load it in blocks and avoids all the nastiness of divided blocks.

A tokenizer is just an implementation of a finite state machine. (You should take note that a regular expression is also just a definition of a finite state machine.) All you have to do is identify what your states are and when you're done creating a lexeme. Since you have a pretty small set of states to work with, this actually isn't that hard. The idea is pretty basic. You write a big if/else block that first checks the current state you're in (which you got to by looking at the previous characters) and then some more conditional logic based on what the current character is.

As a by the way, if you want to understand all this stuff better, take a course on compilers. The concepts and techniques you'll learn there are *immensely* useful for complex text processing. It's a little amazing how they pop up as good solutions while you're building things surrounding processing a piece of text.

Tokenizer code tends to be kind of long and ugly, but it's pretty standard. The fact it more or less follows a standard pattern makes it relatively comprehensible, but most importantly, it *works*. I've written one up below. There might be shorter ways of writing the checks for multiple numbers, but I just did it the long way to make it simpler to understand what's going on. I've not actually tested this code, so test thoroughly and debug, but the logic should be sound. Good luck.

```
import re

# Gonna be using this a lot, so compile it.
digit_pattern = re.compile('[0-9]')

# We're creating a class because there's a little bit of state to maintain.
class OracleErrorFinder(object):
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.input_file = input_file
        # This seems weird, but there's a good reason.
        # When we get to the end of a match, we're going to have already consumed
        # the next character from the file. So we need to save it for the next round.
        next_char = None

    def find_next_match(self):
        # Possible states are
        # '': We haven't found any portion of the pattern yet.
        # 'O': We found an O
        # 'R': We found an OR
        # 'A': We found an ORA
        # '-': We found an ORA-
        # 'num1': We found ORA-[0-9]
        # 'num2': We found ORA-[0-9][0-9]
        # 'num3': We found ORA-[0-9][0-9][0-9]
        # 'num4': We found ORA-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
        # 'num5': We found ORA-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9], and we're done

        current_state = ''
        match_so_far = ''
        done = False
        while not done:
            if self.next_char:
                # If we have a leftover char from last time, 
                # start with that and clear it.
                c = self.next_char
                self.next_char = None
            else:
                c = self.input_file.read(1)

            if '' == c:
               match_so_far = None
               done = True # End of stream and we didn't find a match. Time to stop.
            elif '' == current_state and 'O' == c:
                # We found the start of what we're looking for.
                # We don't know if it's the whole thing,
                # so we just save it and go to the next character.
                current_state = 'O'
                match_so_far = 'O'
            elif 'O' == current_state and 'R' == c:
                # We already have an O and now we found the next character!
                current_state = 'R'
                match_so_far += c
            elif 'R' == current_state and 'A' == c:
                current_state = 'A'
                match_so_far += c
            elif 'A' == current_state and '-' == c:
                current_state = '-'
                match_so_far += c
            elif '-' == current_state and digit_pattern.match(c):
                current_state = 'num1'
                match_so_far += c
            elif 'num1' == current_state:
                if digit_pattern.match(c):
                    current_state = 'num2'
                    match_so_far += c
                else:
                    # We found a full match,
                    # but not more numbers past the last one.
                    # Time to return what we found.
                    done = True
            elif 'num2' == current_state:
                if digit_pattern.match(c):
                    current_state = 'num3'
                    match_so_far += c
                else:
                    # We found a full match,
                    # but not more numbers past the last one.
                    # Time to return what we found.
                    done = True
            elif 'num3' == current_state:
                if digit_pattern.match(c):
                    current_state = 'num4'
                    match_so_far += c
                else:
                    # We found a full match,
                    # but not more numbers past the last one.
                    # Time to return what we found.
                    done = True
            elif 'num4' == current_state:
                if digit_pattern.match(c):
                    current_state = 'num5'
                    match_so_far += c
                else:
                    # We found a full match,
                    # but not more numbers past the last one.
                    # Time to return what we found.
                    done = True
            elif 'num5' == current_state:
                # We're done for sure!
                # Note that we read the next character from the file.
                # Important for code after the loop.
                done = True
            else:
                # We didn't find the next character we wanted.
                if 'O' == c:
                    # We didn't find a full match, but this starts
                    # a new one.
                    current_state = 'O'
                    match_so_far = 'O'
                else:
                    # This character doesn't match our pattern.
                    # It could be a character that's in the wrong place
                    # (such as the - in OR-) or a character that just
                    # doesn't appear in the pattern at all (like X).
                    # We might be in the middle of a partial
                    # match, so throw everything found so far away
                    # and keep going.
                    current_state = ''
                    match_so_far = ''

        # Save next char already consumed from file stream.
        # Could be empty string if we consumed the whole file,
        # but that's fine.
        self.next_char = c
        return match_so_far

with open(filename) as f:
    finder = OracleErrorFinder(f)
    while True:
        match = finder.find_next_match()
        if None is match:
            break
        # Print, send to file, add to list, what have you
```

Comment: @Ryan I just made some edits/fixes. Sorry for the bugs.

Comment: That's great, I ended up with a similar solution.  I appreciate the thought behind your answer. I wasn't able to search for the concept without those key terms.  Thank you for the explanation.  I'm also accepting it as the answer because it does utilize the design pattern I indicated.  The downside to this approach was that it was a little slower than I had hoped for.  I did design a version of it still using regex which was slightly more performant (at the cost of complexity/lines of code).  As soon as I have a chance to clean up the code I'll post.